# no metadata found in activereocrd-3.2.9.gem when running bundle install in a rails 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, bundle

am a newbie in rails. working on Windows 7, 64 bits. Installed my environment through RailsInstaller. latest version ofcourse.
When creating a new project, (keeping the gem file as default) and having the bundle install run, am getting the error

```
gem::package::FormatError: no metadata found in 
D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/cashe/activereocrd-3.2.9.gem
and error occurrend while installing activerecord (3.2.9), and bubndler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install activerecord -v '3.2.9' succeeds before building.
```

I tried to run the gem install activerecord..as instructed still bundle install does not work and i cannot run the rails server. (rails s)

When changing the rails version in the app gem file to 3.2.8 instead of 3.2.9 everything seems to work and the rails server runs succefully. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled railsinstaller and all other leftover folders.
reinstalled railsinstaller. Problem solved.